# Directly jump to a row in csv - using csvhelper class

Tags: c#, csvhelper

How I can directly jump to a row of a csv file ? Please see the below shown structure of csv. I want to jump directly to the row 3 (skip 0,1,2 rows) using csvhelper class ? RowId is a column in the csv file.

```
              RowId  Name
              -----  ----
               0     Raju
               1     Sabu
               2     Ravi
               3     Lal
               4     Babu
```

Here is how I read csv file :

```
    CsvConfiguration csvConfiguration = new CsvConfiguration(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
        {
            HasHeaderRecord = true,
            Delimiter = ",",
            PrepareHeaderForMatch = args => args.Header.ToUpper(),
            IgnoreBlankLines = true,
            IgnoreReferences = true,             
            MissingFieldFound = null,
            UseNewObjectForNullReferenceMembers = true
        };

        CsvReader csv = new CsvReader(File.OpenText(FileNameWithPath), csvConfiguration);
        csv.Read();
        csv.ReadHeader();

         while (csv.Read())
         {
           string d0 = csv.GetField<string>("Name");
           var d5 = csv.GetField<int>("Class");
         }
```

And thiscsv file contains more than 2000 records. So If I want to jump to a row (eg: 250 rowid) by skipping all the rows just above the rowid=230, how i can do that ?
After finding this rowid = 230, i also want to start reading from row id 230 onwards.
How we can do that using csvhelper with c#?

Comment: You can't. Iterating row by row until you find your starting point is as good as it gets.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use `ShouldSkipRecords`.

```cs
void Main()
{
    var s = new StringBuilder();
    s.Append("RowId,Name\r\n");
    s.Append("0,zero\r\n");
    s.Append("1,one\r\n");
    s.Append("2,two\r\n");
    s.Append("3,three\r\n");
    s.Append("4,four\r\n");
    s.Append("5,five\r\n");
    s.Append("6,six\r\n");
    var config = new CsvConfiguration(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
    {
        ShouldSkipRecord = args => args.Row.Parser.Row > 1 && args.Row.GetField<int>("RowId") < 3,
    };
    using (var reader = new StringReader(s.ToString()))
    using (var csv = new CsvReader(reader, config))
    {   
        csv.GetRecords<Foo>().ToList().Dump();
    }
}

private class Foo
{
    public int RowId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

[image]

Another is to read manually.

```cs
void Main()
{
    var s = new StringBuilder();
    s.Append("RowId,Name\r\n");
    s.Append("0,zero\r\n");
    s.Append("1,one\r\n");
    s.Append("2,two\r\n");
    s.Append("3,three\r\n");
    s.Append("4,four\r\n");
    s.Append("5,five\r\n");
    s.Append("6,six\r\n");
    var config = new CsvConfiguration(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
    {
    };
    using (var reader = new StringReader(s.ToString()))
    using (var csv = new CsvReader(reader, config))
    {   
        var records = new List<Foo>();
        csv.Read();
        csv.ReadHeader();
        while (csv.Read())
        {
            var rowId = csv.GetField<int>("RowId");
            if (rowId < 3)
            {
                continue;
            }
            
            records.Add(csv.GetRecord<Foo>());
        }
        
        records.Dump();
    }
}

private class Foo
{
    public int RowId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

[image]